# PDF Form - Allow Reader to insert Jpegs

Tags: image, forms, pdf, adobe

I am working on an Adobe Form for my customers to allow them to place photos into a PDF Form.

I am currently using 
event.target.buttonImportIcon();

Which is allowing me to place an image if I have full Acrobat but when I go to a computer with Reader Only (version 11) it will only let me select PDFs to place.

I need the browse option to be able to select Jpeg from the drop down menu.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That does not appear to be possible in Reader, only in Acrobat. You can read more (and a few possible work-arounds) here:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1072747?start=0&tstart=0